# How to render the Nepali or Hindi text as label?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

hindi_font = FontProperties(fname = '/home/dip/WebScraping/fonts/Mangal.ttf')
figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
a = [('सरकारले', 3410), ('अर्ब', 3143), ('आर्थिक', 3026), ('रुपैयाँ', 2965),
     ('कारण', 2758), ('काम', 2745), ('व्यवस्था', 2683), ('समेत', 2580)]
b = dict(a)

val_val = b.values()
key_val = b.keys()
plt.bar(key_val,val_val)
plt.show()
```

[Output Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI7mA.png)
But its not getting rendered as seen in the abouve screenshot text is displayed like rectangle boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This method allows you to plot directly using specific fonts. You can choose the font of your choice, as here the `Mangal` font is used according to your choice. All you have to do is apply the font properties to each label.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties


font_prop = FontProperties(fname='Mangal.ttf', size=18)


figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
a = [('सरकारले', 3410), ('अर्ब', 3143), ('आर्थिक', 3026), ('रुपैयाँ', 2965),
     ('कारण', 2758), ('काम', 2745), ('व्यवस्था', 2683), ('समेत', 2580)]
b = dict(a)

ax = plt.subplot()

val_val = b.values()
key_val = b.keys()
br = plt.bar(key_val, val_val)


for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_fontproperties(font_prop)
    label.set_fontsize(15)  # Size here overrides font_prop


plt.title("नेपाली भाषामा शीर्षक", fontproperties=font_prop,
          size=22, verticalalignment='bottom')  # Size here overrides font_prop
plt.xlabel("लेबलहरू", fontproperties=font_prop)
plt.ylabel("लेबलहरू", fontproperties=font_prop)


plt.show()
```

I also gave titles and labels using Google Translate. I don't know Nepali, apology if the translation is stupid.

[image: python matplotlib bar with unicode]